# JSON Array.Reduce multidimensional

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to gathering an consolidated sum from this example:

```
[
    [
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"318","value":"1000000","opposite":"282"},
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"316","value":"1000000","opposite":"280"}
    ],
    [
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"318","value":"1000000","opposite":"282"},
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"316","value":"1000000","opposite":"280"}
    ],
    [
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"318","value":"1000000","opposite":"282"},
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"316","value":"1000000","opposite":"280"}
    ],
    [
        {"mode":"income","id":"282","value":"3000000","opposite":"318"}
    ],
    [
        {"mode":"income","id":"280","value":"3000000","opposite":"316"}
    ]
]
```

In the previous sample we have duplicated values and the purposal y sum to compare with another objects in mode "income". Already try with loop but I have a headache in how to compare the outcome mode with income.

I hope to be clear with my question. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to get the total sum of the values?

Comment: What is being summed? How are duplicate values relevant? What "proposal"? Can you post the loop you attempted? Can you post example output?

Answer (score 0):

You could run a nested for loop:

```js
let data = [
    [
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"318","value":"1000000","opposite":"282"},
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"316","value":"1000000","opposite":"280"}
    ],
    [
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"318","value":"1000000","opposite":"282"},
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"316","value":"1000000","opposite":"280"}
    ],
    [
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"318","value":"1000000","opposite":"282"},
        {"mode":"outcome","id":"316","value":"1000000","opposite":"280"}
    ],
    [
        {"mode":"income","id":"282","value":"3000000","opposite":"318"}
    ],
    [
        {"mode":"income","id":"280","value":"3000000","opposite":"316"}
    ]
];

let x = 0;
data.forEach(e => {
    e.forEach(c => {
        x = x + parseInt(c["value"])
    })
});
console.log('SUM:', x);
```

Then, you extract the value of `x` to see the total "values"

Comment: No need for `x` and `f` - just add `parseInt(c['value'])` directly onto `x`